# Python - Using re to search for a pattern in the value of an imported csv for an if statement

Tags: python, regex, csv

First, I apologize for being a noob at this. I have the following code that opens a CSV file and reads it. I'm trying to only return rows that contain a public IP address in the field called 'Source IP / Details' as well as the row['Status'] fields which I know are working.  I have what I believe to be is a correct regex but I'm not sure I'm doing the search correctly.  Also, I'm not sure I'm setting the variable correctly in the following for statement.

```
ipRegex = '\b(?!(10)|192\.168|172\.(2[0-9]|1[6-9]|3[0-2]))[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'

with open('whois.csv') as csvDataFile:
csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile)
rows = [row for row in csvReader if row['Status'] != "Closed" and row['Status'] != "Resolved"] and row['Source IP / Details'] == re.search(ipRegex, row['Source IP / Details'])]

for row in rows:
    case = row['Case Number']
    ipaddr = row['Source IP / Details']
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Case Number,Status,Date/Time Opened,_BATCH_ID_,_BATCH_LAST_RUN_,Alert Source,Alert Subtype,Source IP / Details,
2926,Closed,2015-10-29T11:54:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Sophos,[MEDIUM] Alert for Sophos Cloud: A computer does not comply with its Cloud po...,,
7733,Closed,2015-11-18T13:46:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Malicious Network Activity,216.30.178.102,
7818,Closed,2015-11-18T20:58:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Application-Specific Exploits GNU Bash Environment Variable Code Injection attempt(s),,
7850,Closed,2015-11-18T21:47:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Vulnerability Scanning,173.166.95.81,
```

Comment: Please provide some lines of `whois.csv` and correct your indents by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47025645/edit). Additonally, your regex does not match an ip address (see here: https://regex101.com/r/uzRthC/1)  and the last `)` after `$` yields a pattern error.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to correct the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for `is not None` when looking for a match. Additionally, as stated in your comments, there was an error in your expression. I changed the last line to `Open` to produce a result:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv, re

data = """Case Number,Status,Date/Time Opened,_BATCH_ID_,_BATCH_LAST_RUN_,Alert Source,Alert Subtype,Source IP / Details,
2926,Closed,2015-10-29T11:54:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Sophos,[MEDIUM] Alert for Sophos Cloud: A computer does not comply with its Cloud po...,,
7733,Closed,2015-11-18T13:46:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Malicious Network Activity,216.30.178.102,
7818,Closed,2015-11-18T20:58:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Application-Specific Exploits GNU Bash Environment Variable Code Injection attempt(s),,
7850,Open,2015-11-18T21:47:00,2130,2017-10-30T22:48:02,Dell SecureWorks,Vulnerability Scanning,173.166.95.81,"""

rx = re.compile(r'^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!\.255$)$')

with StringIO(data) as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile)

    rows = [row for row in csvReader 
            if row['Status'] != 'Closed' and row['Status'] != 'Resolved' 
            and rx.search(row['Source IP / Details']) is not None]
    print(rows)
```

This yields

```
[OrderedDict([('Case Number', '7850'), ('Status', 'Open'), ('Date/Time Opened', '2015-11-18T21:47:00'), ('_BATCH_ID_', '2130'), ('_BATCH_LAST_RUN_', '2017-10-30T22:48:02'), ('Alert Source', 'Dell SecureWorks'), ('Alert Subtype', 'Vulnerability Scanning'), ('Source IP / Details', '173.166.95.81'), ('', '')])]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much.